# Applying SSL Certificates using AWS / EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, https

I'm attempting to add an SSL certificate to a couple of websites via AWS.

I'm more of a designer/programmer than a network/server guy, and this is becoming sort of a challenge. Please help a poor soul.

I have a single EC2 instance, running Windows w/ IIS.

Here's a couple things I've tried thus far:

1) I went to the Certificate Manager via the AWS Console. I was stopped in my tracks because this feature only seems to be available for the `US East (N. Virginia)` region currently; my server is in `US West (Oregon)` and I can't really justify changing that. I suppose that's a no go?

2) Uncle Google tells me that most [other means](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ssl-server-cert.html) of adding certs involve having a Load Balancer or a [CDN](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html). The EC2 server in question is only being run for a handful of businesses to use for internal processes, and a little file storage. There's no need for a CDN or Load Balancer, so this seems kind of counter-intuitive.

Does anyone have some knowledge to drop on me? I'd really like to enable SSL certificates on some of these sites without making such big changes. I'm shocked a service like AWS hasn't made this kind of information more available.

Comment: People seem to get hung up on CloudFront being a CDN, as something they "don't need."  In conjunction with ACM, it does *exactly* what you want in this case, and because of the bandwidth pricing structure of CloudFront vs EC2, it costs essentially nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to use Certificate Manager without an ELB or CloudFront anyway. If you don't want to pay for the Load Balancer or use a CDN then you will have to obtain an SSL certificate from an SSL certificate authority and install it directly on IIS.

Comment: Today I learned how to do just that. Way less complicated than I thought. thanks.